# Apache 2.4 with php5

Tags: php, apache, loadmodule

Hi I am trying to run php5 with apache 2.4
Earlier i have tested with php7 with apache 2.4 working fine on windows server 2012.

But when i switched from php7 to php5 a load module error arise.

Cannot start Apache (c:/wamp/php5/php5apache2_4.dll into server: The specified module could not be found)

unable to find why module cannot be loaded it's present  inside the root folder of php5.

Comment: did you add manually php5 on wamp ?

Comment: @MacBooc no i have installed php apache and mysql manually under the folder wamp. There is no wamp server installed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i got my solution after reading the doc at windows.php.net. 
They PHP5 require vc9 vc11 and vc14 compiler in order to run but i installed vc9 anc vc14 earlier and after installing vc11 they able to load my module php5apache2_4.dll and finally Apache run successfully.